# Extracting Coq to Haskell

Tags: haskell, coq

I'm experimenting with Coq's extraction mechanism to Haskell. I wrote a naive predicate for prime numbers in Coq, here it is:

```
(***********)
(* IMPORTS *)
(***********)
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.

(************)
(* helper'' *)
(************)
Fixpoint helper' (p m n : nat) : bool :=
  match m,n with
  | 0,_ => false
  | 1,_ => false
  | _,0 => false
  | _,1 => false
  | S m',S n' => (orb ((mult m n) =? p) (helper' p m' n))
  end.

(**********)
(* helper *)
(**********)
Fixpoint helper (p m : nat) : bool :=
  match m with
  | 0 => false
  | S m' => (orb ((mult m m) =? p) (orb (helper' p m' m) (helper p m')))
  end.

(***********)
(* isPrime *)
(***********)
Fixpoint isPrime (p : nat) : bool :=
  match p with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => false
  | S p' => (negb (helper p p'))
  end.

Compute (isPrime 220).

(*****************)
(* isPrimeHelper *)
(*****************)
Extraction Language Haskell.

(*****************)
(* isPrimeHelper *)
(*****************)
Extraction "/home/oren/GIT/CoqIt/Primes.hs" isPrime helper helper'.
```

And after extracting the Haskell code, I wrote a simple driver to test it. I ran into two issues:

1. Coq exported its own `Bool` instead of using Haskell's built in boolean type.
2. Coq also used its own `nat`, so I can't ask `isPrime 6` and I have to use `S (S (...))`.

```
module Main( main ) where    
import Primes    
main = do
    if ((isPrime (
        Primes.S (
        Primes.S (
        Primes.S (
        Primes.S (
        Primes.S (
        Primes.S ( O ))))))))
        ==
        Primes.True)
    then
        print "Prime"
    else
        print "Non Prime"
```

Comment: This is not a question. What do you hope an answer will contain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding your first point - try to add

```
Require Import ExtrHaskellBasic.
```

to your Coq source. It specifies that the extraction should use Haskell's prelude definitions for some basic types. Documentation can be found [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.extraction.ExtrHaskellBasic.html). There is also a similar module for [strings](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.extraction.ExtrHaskellString.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting a complete solution here to make this post self contained. Hope others can make use of it.

```
(***********)
(* IMPORTS *)
(***********)
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.

(************)
(* helper'' *)
(************)
Fixpoint helper' (p m n : nat) : bool :=
  match m,n with
  | 0,_ => false
  | 1,_ => false
  | _,0 => false
  | _,1 => false
  | S m',S n' => (orb ((mult m n) =? p) (helper' p m' n))
  end.

(**********)
(* helper *)
(**********)
Fixpoint helper (p m : nat) : bool :=
  match m with
  | 0 => false
  | S m' => (orb ((mult m m) =? p) (orb (helper' p m' m) (helper p m')))
  end.

(***********)
(* isPrime *)
(***********)
Fixpoint isPrime (p : nat) : bool :=
  match p with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => false
  | S p' => (negb (helper p p'))
  end.

Compute (isPrime 220).

(********************************)
(* Extraction Language: Haskell *)
(********************************)
Extraction Language Haskell.

(***************************)
(* Use Haskell basic types *)
(***************************)
Require Import ExtrHaskellBasic.

(****************************************)
(* Use Haskell support for Nat handling *)
(****************************************)
Require Import ExtrHaskellNatNum.
Extract Inductive Datatypes.nat => "Prelude.Integer" ["0" "succ"]
"(\fO fS n -> if n Prelude.== 0 then fO () else fS (n Prelude.- 1))".

(***************************)
(* Extract to Haskell file *)
(***************************)
Extraction "/home/oren/GIT/CoqIt/Primes.hs" isPrime helper helper'.
```

And here is the driver:

```
module Main( main ) where

import Primes
import Prelude

main = do
    if ((isPrime 220) == True)
    then
        print "Prime"
    else
        print "Non Prime"
```

It's interesting to mention the huge time difference between Coq's slow `Compute (isPrime 220)` and Haskell's compiled (and optimized!) super fast version of `(is Prime 220)`.

Comment: I don't think the time difference in your last comment is worth mentioning.  Working with type `nat` in Coq is only interesting for proof purposes, not for computation purposes.

Comment: I get `illegal begin of vernac` error when I try to compile it

Comment: @Yves I've posted a question on estimating running times of extracted code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796487/predict-running-times-of-extracted-coq-code-to-haskell ... I wondered if you could answer it? I think it's interesting to be able to predict running times somehow from Coq code itself no?

Comment: @radrow As explained in the beginning of https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.14/refman/addendum/extraction.html, in recent versions of Coq, you apparently need the line `From Coq Require Extraction.` before any extraction commands will work.  If you don't have that line, then you get the `illegal begin of vernac` error when you try to use `Extraction`.  This is at least the case since Coq 8.8, but may also be true in previous versions as well.